# Add and edit in one form php

Tags: php

I have two files .. addclient.php & Editclient.php.

I want to combine in one php form. can u please help me to do this

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
echo "add";
  } else if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo "edit"
  }  
?>
```

if `$id` already exist in the table than the row is updated otherwise it's an `INSERT`.
If you only have an `$id` : show the form with existing data in it.
If it's not a `$id` isn't populated : show an empty form.

Comment: Reason why you're using get over post?

Comment: Actually, keeping the files seperated is a better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
         $id = intval($_GET['id']);
         $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = ?");
         $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
         $stmt->execute();
         if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
               // UPDATE
               // Text field with the id
               echo '<input type="text" name="id" value="'. $id. '"/>';
         } else {
               // INSERT
               // Text field with no id
               echo '<input type="text" name="id"/>';
         }
    }
?>
```

This validates the integer and makes sure it's one, queries the table for that specific id, if there is more than one row with that id then you need to update, else you need to insert.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha From the question "if $id already exist in the table" TABLE.

Comment: cAN U PLEASE EXPLAIN WITH A TEXT FIELD.. IF A ID IS PASSED .. DISPLAY THAT ID IN THE TEXT FIELD OTHER WISE MAKE IT EMPTY

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['ID'])) {
    $ID= $_GET['ID'];
    // Use MySQL with $ID to check if the user is existing, and this string will either be 0 or 1
    $existing = 0; // 0 = New 1 = Existing
    //Add
    if($existing== 0) {

    } 
    //Edit
    if($existing == 1) {

    }    
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo "Edit";
  } else {              
    echo "Add"
  }  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo "update";
  }else{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo "add"
  }  
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if(isset($id) && !empty($id)){
    echo "Update";
}else{
    echo "Add";
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some comments to your answer to describe what does the trick or why this solves the problem!?